# Permission user from different forest

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-server, people-picker, people-search, trusted-domain

A power user recently asked me a question whether or not he can share a site with someone whose account is in a different forest. Obviously he could not find that user through ['Select People and Groups'](https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/en-us/library/gg602067.32f6e39e-9e67-4277-b0f7-547c904bc25e(v=office.14).jpg?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) dialog. As he is not a farm administrator he can't change the [PeoplePicker SearchADForest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460(v=office.12).aspx) property either.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share the solution with everyone. As long as you know the users account name (Active Directory login name in this case) and there is a two way trust between the forests you can use '[Check Names](https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/en-us/library/gg602067.5944af62-6c78-4b54-8918-19b6edc66aac(v=office.14).jpg?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)' to resolve directly. This power user was delighted knowing the trick. Saved him emailing the document from the intranet.

Ob course for the admins they can use [STSADM AddUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262627%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or Powershell [New-SpUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607868.aspx) commands in such scenario. In stead of making a change in the PeoplePicker SearchADForest property.

Hope this helps someone out there!

Thanks for reading.